# Can't search for drafts in Control Panel

Tags: control-panel

I just updated to Craft 3.6x, and I noticed that suddenly all my drafts are showing up by default. This confused users, as there were a bunch of them that people had abandoned. But I noticed that the search filter at the top does not apply to drafts. Is there somewhere to change the setting? And is there also a way to show LIVE entries only, by default?

Comment: Are you upgraded to [3.6.5](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#365---2021-02-10)? Craft changed this recently.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 3.6.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per 3.6.5](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#changed-1), drafts meta data have become searchable (not custom field) and you can (re)index them by running:

```
php craft resave/entries --drafts --update-search-indexes
```

In terms of filtering, you need to manually selete *Live* to hide drafts from the listing.